# Considering all the actual arguments given to a perl function as scalar

Tags: perl, command

I have a perl script `generator.pl` that defines some routines like:

```
sub a($) {
 ...
 print FILE "$_[0]";
 ...
}    

 ...

sub b($$) {
 ...
 print FILE "$_[0], $_[1]";
 ...
}
 ...

$subsfile = $ARGV[0] . "/subs.pl";
$generatedfile = $ARGV[0] . "/generated.file";

open FILE, '>>', "$generatedfile" or die "error trying to append: $!";
do "$subsfile";
close FILE;
```

Let's assume that, for example `subs.pl` is like this:

```
a(1);
a(x);
b(1-2, z);
b(1-x, i);
b(y-z, j);
```

I call `generator script` in this way:

```
C:\Users\Me>perl generator.pl "D:/another/path"
```

Result is that `D:/another/path/generated.file` is created but it contains 0 bytes. Printing `"print $@;"` after `do statement`, I'm obtaining:

```
Transliteration pattern not terminated at...
```

If I try to call the script with a `subs.pl` having each actual argument *double quoted*

```
a("1");
a("x");
b("1-2", "z");
b("1-x", "i");
...
```

it works.

How can I do to make things work without using double quotes?

Comment: so you would like to know why, for example `perl -e '1-x'` doesn't compile but `perl -e '"1-x"'` does?

Comment: Maybe I got solution reading [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#-e-commandline).
Actually, i moved from *linux* to *windows* and with precision under linux it worked.
Routines I'm calling are stored in the file `subs.pl`. Assuming that is it possible to call this routines in this way: `perl -e a(<>)` or `perl -e b(<>, <>)`, in linux it was working (that means *it was compiling*) calling them `perl -e a(2)` or `perl -e b(1-5, x)`. Under windows it doesen't.

Comment: There is no significant different between Linux and Windows versions of Perl. There is certainly no additional *"precision under linux"*. `b(1-x, i)` will *never* compile under *any* version of Perl, but it won't generate the error `Transliteration pattern not terminated`. You show no instance of transliteration at all so it is impossible to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr///` is [**transliteration operator**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) which can be also written as `y///`. Further, it can be modified to take another character as delimiter, ie. `y---`.

So when perl see something like,

```
b(y-z, j);
```

it expects

```
b(y-z, j--);
```

which is correct and would in example above count all occurrences of `z`, `,`, , and `j` chars in default variable `$_`, and pass it as argument to `b()`.

Since compiler expectations are not met, it throws:

> Transliteration pattern not terminated at...

Comment: +1 for revealing the source of `Transliteration pattern not terminated`.